# Remove a constant from every cell of a column in an Excel equation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, equation

I have a column of coefficients and values

```
(Column A) (column B)
0.5         17.0
0.2         15.0
1.0         21.0
0.7         30.0
```

And I want to sum a constant and each coefficients in the column, e.g.

```
(1.0-0.5)*17.0 + (1.0-0.2)*15.0 + (1.0-1.0)*21.0 + (1.0-0.7)*30.0
```

Here, the constant is 1.0. What is the equation that is needed to achieve that? I have tried something like

```
SUMPRODUCT((1-A:A),B:B)
```

Without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=COUNT(A:A)-SUM(A:A)
```

This for for the constant **1**.  If the constant was **7** then use:

```
=7 * COUNT(A:A)-SUM(A:A)
```

**EDIT#1:**

Based on your *Edit*, I tried your proposed formula and it worked just fine!:

[image]

Comment: It bypass the need  to express the problem under the form stated above. But the problem stated before was a simpler version of the real problem, that is why I stated it like that. I made the problem more accurate to reflect the real case use, and unfortunately, the problem cannot be solved with the use of the COUNT function like you mentionned.

Comment: @AlexandreWillame  See my **EDIT#1**  there is nothing wrong with your formula!

Comment: You are right! After checking my own sheet, the problem actually arise because the title was taken into account when I have input A:A. I removed the title, and it worked just fine.... Thank you for the help!

Comment: @AlexandreWillame  You have done a great job debugging the problem!